# Converting daily data to summed/averaged monthly data with a specific layout format

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I've looked through similar past questions but have yet to find something specific to what I'm looking for.

I have daily data, that I would like to convert to average/sum monthly data. With the final product being a dataframe with months in the column and years in the rows [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYamv.png).

I've managed to get the monthly average of my dataset using:

```
library(xts)
ts <- xts(data$tmax, as.Date(data$date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
ts_m = apply.monthly(ts, mean)

    data$Date   data$tmax
1   1951-01-01  3.22777778
2   1951-01-02  6.48888889
3   1951-01-03  10.52777778
4   1951-01-04  1.92777778
5   1951-01-05  1.30000000
6   1951-01-06  0.10000000
7   1951-01-07  -6.72777778
8   1951-01-08  -4.48888889
9   1951-01-09  -0.83888889
10  1951-02-01  -9.92777778
11  1951-02-02  -11.60000000
12  1951-02-03  -8.61111111
13  1951-02-04  -1.40000000
... ...        ...
```

The code above gives me an xts with the averages:

```
Y-M-D       Tmax_avg
1951-01-09  1.279630
1951-02-12  -3.548611
```

But I can't figure out out to convert the layout of the xts (or if I have to convert the xts) so that it looks like this (months running down, and years running across):

```
   1951   1952  1953
01 1.27   ...
02 -3.54  ...
...   
12 ...    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the 'year' and the 'Date' and then use `xtabs`

```
Year <- format(as.Date(index(tsm)), '%Y')
Month <- format(as.Date(index(tsm)), '%m')
df1 <- data.frame(Year, Month, tmax = tsm[,1])
xtabs(tmax ~ Month + Year, df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I'm getting an error when I try to create Year an Month:
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument

Comment: @TAD Do you have `Date` class for `tsm[,1]`. Please check the `str(tsm)`

Comment: No, but I do have a POSIXct if that helps.     Error:   

An ‘xts’ object on 1951-01-09/1951-03-19 containing:
  Data: num [1:3, 1] 1.28 -3.55 4.24
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

Comment: @TAD your `tsm` format was not clear in the quesiton.  May be you need `format(index(tsm), '%Y')`

Comment: I tried that and for '%m' and unfortunately got the same error, Error in prettyNum

Comment: @TAD what is the output of `as.Date(index(tsm))` and `format(as.Date(index(tsm)), '%m')`

Comment: as.Date --> [1] "1951-01-09" "1951-02-12" "1951-03-19" and format --> [1] "01" "02" "03"

Comment: @TAD I updated the post.  In the `data.frame(Year, Month, tmax = tsm[,2])` not sure if it is `tsm[,1]` or so

Comment: @TAD can you please dput your example i.e. `dput(tsm)`

Comment: Yes, it's ts_m[,1]! One last question. is it possible to export the product/layout of xtabs(tmax ~ Month + Year, df1) as excel/csv file?

Comment: @TAD It is a matrix, so it should work.  Otherwise, you can convert to a data.frame with `as.data.frame

Comment: You're right, I just had to format () the last line to create the matrix, then create with data.frame. Thank you so much, you've saved me literally hours or work (I have to do this for 20 datasets)